# how can i disable ssl verification while sending Http POST request?

Tags: java, ssl

when i execute this code

```
   url = new URL(url);
   urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   urlConnection.connect();
```

i get this message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

How can i disable ssl ?

Comment: You cannot just disable SSL.

Comment: *If* the server supports (at least) this resource on both https and http, change the https: at the beginning of the URL to http:. Alternatively, if the *only* error is the cert not having a matching hostname but it is otherwise valid, you can write a (tiny) class that `implements javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier` to accept whatever certs/names you want and apply it to a given `HttpsURLConnection` or as the default for all. Note that if you accept any cert/name, an active attacker may be able to redirect your connections to a fake server and access or modify your data, as they also can for http.

Comment: PS: Http[s]URLConnection defaults to GET. You'll only get POST if you set it explicitly or use `.setDoOutput(true)` and provide a (request) body.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply disable `SSL` from client side. `SSL` is there for security. If the client can just disable it, no purpose of having it in the first place.

However if you are writing the server side as well, you can disable it. It depends on your server/implementation.